# can two different brands have the same name and similar products in two different countries?

Tags: name

I have the perfect name for a new clothing brand. But, i found that another clothing brand in a completely different country has the same name as mine. What should i do?

Comment: It can cause problems if you want to expand internationally. There are some products in NZ which are similar to UK products with the same name but not made under license. Not a legal reference, but for an example of the mess - https://www.telegraph.co.uk/expat/expatnews/9518075/British-expat-in-New-Zealand-Marmite-dispute.html

Answer (score 3):

The specific case depends on whether the foreign brand has protected their name in your country (you have very little chance), or whether the foreign brand is already well-known in your country (you might be up for a major fight and lose).

There is the possibility that the foreign brand might grow and wants to expand into your country, in which case you might get involved in a fight with them, no matter who is legally right. For an example how that can end, visit www.nissan.com . It may not be a risk you want to take.